# Laravel eloquent call realtionship based on a boolean parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to make a method to retrieve model with a relationship I'd like to be able to fetch the relation based on a boolean parameter
for example, I can do it using the if condition like the following

```
if($load == true){
   $users = User::with('login')->all()->paginate();
}else{
$users = User::all()->paginate();
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without the if condition on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `when()` method on the query builder. Note that you don't need to use the `all()` method when you want to use a paginator.

```php
User::query()
    ->when($load, fn($query) => $query->with('login'))
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can use [when](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) method:

```
 $users = User::when($load, function ($query) {
                    return $query->with('login');
                })->paginate(10);
```

The when method only executes the given closure when the first argument is true. If the first argument is false, the closure will not be executed

Comment: Thank you it worked